# add file accept function in jinja populated FileField

Tags: html, jinja2

I'm populating several file file using jinja :

```
{{ form.resume_copy }}
```

in browser output it'll look like this

```
<input type="file" name="resume_copy" required="" id="id_resume_copy">
```

how can I add `accept` function so it can only accept pdf like this :

```
<input type="file" name="resume_copy" required="" id="id_resume_copy" accept="application/pdf">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I just use

```
$("#id_resume_copy").prop("accept", "application/pdf")
```